# iPhone : how to get recording time using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, avaudioplayer

how can i recognize the duration of my recording that is recorded by the user.

Here Recording time is not decided, so user can record how much time he/she wants.

so I want to `recognize` that my recording is going to be `finish` now, and then after I want to give some action.

So How do I get that duration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the Good example of Audio recording.](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29)

Comment: Please [provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include some real content directly in your answer. Use the link as a reference for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use NSTimer to schedule specified time to record and after time expires stop recording....